# Throwing an exception without "Exception in thread..."

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception, throwable

I would like to know if there's a simple way of throwing an exception, but **ONLY** with the exact string I choose. I found a way to get rid of the stack trace, but now I want to remove the beginning of every exception:

"Exception in thread "main" RuntimeException..."

I'm looking for a simple, elegant way to do this (not super simple, but not way too complicated as well).

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Hmm... seems kinda redundant to me since what your asking for is just `try{...}catch(Exception e){System.err.print("what ever");}`

Comment: No particular reason, I'd just like to know if such thing is possible and how.

Comment: The goal is to crash the program by throwing an exception, not printing out a simple string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to set your own, custom, [uncaught exception handler:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-)

```
public static void main(String... argv)
{
  Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> System.err.println(e.getMessage()));
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Goodbye, World!");
}
```

Comment: Won't the `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Goodbye, World!");` print `Exception in thread...` which is pretty much what the op was trying to avid... You 100% right about the correct way though.

Comment: @DimaMaligin Try it and see.

Comment: @edle fell free to reaccept the answer... this is the right way.

Comment: That is the correct way. If I change it to System.err.print(e.getMessage()); it should be just what I wanted. This also avoids stack trace, which is good. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do we need to do this before every Illegal Arg Exception in code?

Comment: @KrisSwat No, just do it once, early in the program so that it’s ready if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.print("what ever");
    System.exit(1); // close the program
}
```

Comment: Why did I forget about System.err.print()? :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it :

```
try{
   //your code
 }catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Whatever you want to print" + e.getMessage());
   System.exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: That's a simple printout... I want to stop the program by throwing an exception.

Comment: Like adding System.exit in the catch clause ?

Answer (score 0):

When you construct an exception object, one of the constructors will take a String object of the message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, except if you get openJDK, change the sources and recompile.

However, what most developers usually do is to use some logging library such as log4j and use different detail levels, according to the logging settings.

So you can print the full stacktrace using a lower level such as TRACE or DEBUG and a more human-readable message in the ERROR or WARN (or even INFO) levels.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but if you just add "throws Exception" to the method header and throw the exception in the method where it should fail, that should work.

Example:

```
public void HelloWorld throws Exception{
    if(//condition that causes failure)
        throw new Exception("Custom Error Message");
    else{
        //other stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a custom `Exception` that you can create yourself.

- These exceptions can either be `Checked` exceptions, that are enforced by Java compiler (Requires try/catch or throws to implement)
- Or the exception can be `Unchecked` exception, which throws during runtime, that are not enforced by the Java compiler.

Based on what you have written, it seems you want an `Unchecked` exception that is not enforced, but throws an error during runtime.

One way of doing this is through the following:

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
       CustomException() {
              super("Runtime exception: problem is..."); // Throws this error message if no message was specified.
       }

       CustomException(String errorMessage) {
            super(errorMessage); // Write your own error message using throw new CustomException("There was a problem. This is a custom error message"); 
       }
}
```

Then in your code, you could do the following:

```
public class Example {
    String name = "x";
    if(name.equals("x"))
          throw new CustomException();   // refers to CustomException()
}
```

Or

```
 public class Example2 {
        String name = "y";
        if(name.equals("y")) 
             throw new CustomException("Error. Your name should not be this letter/word."); // Refers to CustomException(String errorMessage);
 }
```

You can also do this for Throwable as well.

Comment: This is very basic exception handling... I was trying to avoid the stack trace and the beginning of every exception text.